# Conflict in css

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have many css files which make it conflict with each other.

All elements in the project should have the flowing css style

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box; }
```

while there is only a dialog that should not have this css

```
<div id="WebcamPopup">
.....
</div>
```

is there a solution for this problem  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#WebcamPopup, #WebcamPopup *, #WebcamPopup *:after, #WebcamPopup *:before {
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Having said that - you're demonstrating *exactly* why you shouldn't do invasive stuff like `box-sizing` overrides globally.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be overriding the [`boz-sizing`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing) for that specific selector:

```css
#WebcamPopup,
#WebcamPopup:before,
#WebcamPopup:after { box-sizing: content-box; }
```

The *initial* value of `box-sizing` is `content-box`.

> **[6.1. ‘box-sizing’ property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing)**
>
> **content-box**
>   This is the behavior of width and height as specified by CSS2.1. The specified width and height (and respective
>   min/max properties) apply to the width and height respectively of the
>   content box of the element. The padding and border of the element are
>   laid out and drawn outside the specified width and height.

You could also use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) keyword if it's an option but note that it is not supported in IE.